# Split view on MacOS 12: very long animation after key shortcut using

Tags: macos, shortcut, split-view

It has normal behaviour when I hovered over a "green button" of a window, then pressed on "**Tile Window to Left of Screen**". But when I use a key-shortcut, which I set by myself, there is a long animation before it settled.

[image]

How to disable animation on key-shortcut?

I tried some ways:

1.

```
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.003
```

2. 

```
# resizing windows before and after showing the version browser
# also disabled by NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
defaults write -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation -bool false
```

3. **Accessibility** > **Display** > **Reduce Motion** [true]

Comment: As long as this bug exists, I'll use spectacle. This might help you as well.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be some weird bug related to the "shift"-key. After removing "shift" from my shortcut, the animation worked as intended. The same happened to others as well, e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252663622

Comment: Right! thanks. removing the shift key from the keyboard shortcut worked for me also. After a long time trying to figure out what causes this. I hope they'll fix this issue soon.

Comment: Same problem and solution on Sonoma.